# trying to make a average list for a bowling club

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make an average list for a bowling club. I have a database with the following tables:

- `team_medlem   (medlem_id, name, address, etc)`
- `team_samling  (match_id, lag_id, borta (0 = home game, 1 = away game), date, time, etc)`
- `team_match    (id, match_id, s1, s2, etc)`
- `team_resultat (id, medlem_id, results, series, banp, match_id)`

I want to get the total average, average home and away average. result is the total points for the entire game for each player and the series is the number of played series.
I have this:

```
SELECT team_resultat.medlem_id, team_medlem.namn, sum(resultat)/sum(serier) as snitt, sum(banp)
FROM team_resultat 
JOIN team_medlem ON team_resultat.medlem_id = team_medlem.medlem_id 
JOIN team_samling ON team_resultat.match_id = team_samling.match_id
WHERE datum >= current_date - interval '1' year
GROUP BY namn
ORDER BY snitt desc
```

How can I get home average and away average?

I have tried this but it miscalculated averages

```
SELECT team_resultat.medlem_id, team_medlem.namn, sum(resultat)/sum(serier) as snitt, sum(banp), avg(case when not borta then resultat/serier end) as hemmasnitt, avg(case when borta then   resultat/serier end) as bortasnitt
FROM team_resultat 
JOIN team_medlem ON team_resultat.medlem_id = team_medlem.medlem_id 
JOIN team_samling ON team_resultat.match_id = team_samling.match_id
WHERE datum >= current_date - interval '1' year
GROUP BY namn
ORDER BY snitt desc
```

Sampeldata:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Värd: 127.0.0.1
-- Tid vid skapande: 03 nov 2014 kl 20:07
-- Serverversion: 5.6.17
-- PHP-version: 5.5.12
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
--
-- Databas: `teamet`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Tabellstruktur `team_medlem`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_medlem` (
`medlem_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`namn` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`medlem_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci COMMENT='Medlems register'AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;
--
-- Dumpning av Data i tabell `team_medlem`
--
INSERT INTO `team_medlem` (`medlem_id`, `namn`) VALUES
(1, 'Sven-Åke Jansson'),
(2, 'Christer Wendel'),
(4, 'Sören Carlsson'),
(5, 'Jan Ingvarsson'),
(6, 'Lars-Göran Wetterholm'),
(7, 'Anders Svensson'),
(8, 'Bengt Carlsson'),
(9, 'Per-Olof Johansson'),
(10, 'Barsom Calan'),
(11, 'Mikael Mårtensson'),
(12, 'Andreas Johansson'),
(13, 'Jonas Wendel'),
(14, 'Sören Fransson'),
(15, 'Daniel Fransson'),
(16, 'Stefan Lord'),
(18, 'Lennart Johansson'),
(19, 'Jonas Nilsson'),
(20, 'Mikael Nilsson'),
(21, 'Patrik Emanuelsson'),
(22, 'Jörgen Norman'),
(24, 'Anders Johansson'),
(25, 'Andreas Larsson'),
(26, 'Roger Larsson'),
(27, 'Peter Ericson'),
(28, 'Dado Hrnic'),
(29, 'Maria Lord-Johansson'),
(33, 'Mats Wellermark');

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Värd: 127.0.0.1
-- Tid vid skapande: 03 nov 2014 kl 20:13
-- Serverversion: 5.6.17
-- PHP-version: 5.5.12
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
--
-- Databas: `teamet`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Tabellstruktur `team_samling`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_samling` (
 `match_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`omg` int(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`borta` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`datum` date DEFAULT NULL,
`tid` time DEFAULT NULL,
`motstandare` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`samling` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ovrigt` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci COMMENT='Samling' AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
--
-- Dumpning av Data i tabell `team_samling`
--
INSERT INTO `team_samling` (`match_id`, `lag_id`, `omg`, `borta`, `datum`, `tid`, `motstandare`, `samling`, `ovrigt`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 0, '2014-10-28', '12:15:00', 'Forsheda', '11:30', 'match dräkt'),
(2, 2, 1, 0, '2014-10-27', '10:00:00', 'Jönköping KK', '09:15', ''),
(3, 3, 3, 0, '2014-10-30', '15:20:00', 'Alvesta', '14:30', ''),
(4, 2, 2, 1, '2014-11-05', '12:00:00', 'Sävsjö', '09:15', 'Buss'),
(5, 2, 2, 1, '2014-11-05', '14:00:00', 'Eksjö', NULL, NULL),
(6, 3, 2, 0, '2014-11-06', '11:15:00', 'Jönköping kk', '10:30', NULL),
(11, 1, 20, 1, '2014-11-05', '12:30:00', 'test borta 2', '09:30', NULL),
(13, 1, 22, 0, '2014-11-06', '10:00:00', 'Test hemma', '09:00', NULL);

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Värd: 127.0.0.1
-- Tid vid skapande: 03 nov 2014 kl 20:16
-- Serverversion: 5.6.17
-- PHP-version: 5.5.12
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
--
-- Databas: `teamet`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Tabellstruktur `team_resultat`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_resultat` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`medlem_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`resultat` decimal(5,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`serier` int(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`banp` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`match_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`resultat_sparad` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci COMMENT='Match resultat' AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;
--
-- Dumpning av Data i tabell `team_resultat`
--
INSERT INTO `team_resultat` (`id`, `medlem_id`, `resultat`, `serier`, `banp`, `match_id`, `resultat_sparad`) VALUES
(1, 6, '800.00', 4, 3, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(2, 7, '790.00', 4, 3, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(3, 11, '780.00', 4, 2, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(4, 12, '770.00', 4, 2, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(5, 14, '760.00', 4, 3, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(6, 15, '750.00', 4, 2, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(7, 24, '740.00', 4, 2, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(8, 25, '505.00', 3, 1, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(9, 27, '165.00', 1, 0, 2, '2014-10-11 17:11:37'),
(10, 8, '700.00', 4, 2, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(11, 9, '690.00', 4, 3, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(12, 10, '680.00', 4, 2, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(13, 13, '670.00', 4, 2, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(14, 19, '660.00', 4, 2, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(15, 20, '650.00', 4, 1, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(16, 22, '640.00', 4, 2, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(17, 25, '640.00', 4, 1, 1, '2014-10-26 14:29:20'),
(19, 1, '800.00', 4, 2, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(20, 2, '790.00', 4, 2, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(21, 4, '780.00', 4, 2, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(22, 5, '770.00', 4, 2, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(23, 7, '760.00', 4, 2, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(24, 8, '750.00', 4, 2, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(25, 14, '740.00', 4, 3, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(26, 15, '500.00', 3, 1, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(27, 18, '150.00', 1, 1, 3, '2014-10-26 14:31:00'),
(28, 2, '800.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(29, 6, '790.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(30, 11, '780.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(31, 12, '770.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(32, 14, '760.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(33, 15, '750.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(34, 25, '740.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(35, 33, '730.00', 4, 2, 4, '2014-10-26 16:57:47'),
(36, 2, '800.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(37, 6, '790.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(38, 11, '780.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(39, 12, '770.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(40, 14, '760.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(41, 15, '750.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(42, 25, '740.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(43, 33, '730.00', 4, 2, 5, '2014-10-26 16:58:26'),
(44, 10, '700.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(45, 13, '690.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(46, 16, '680.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(47, 19, '670.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(48, 18, '660.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(49, 21, '650.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(50, 26, '640.00', 4, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(51, 27, '520.00', 3, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15'),
(52, 29, '160.00', 1, 2, 6, '2014-10-26 16:59:15');
```

expected results

- Namn                 Snitt   Hemma   Borta   Banp
- Sven-Åke Jansson     200,00  200,00  0   2
- Christer Wendel  199,17  197,50  200,00  6
- Lars-Göran Wetterholm 198,33 200,00  197,50  7
- Mikael Mårtensson    195,00  195,00  195,00  6
- Sören Carlsson   195,00  195,00  0   2
- Anders Svensson  193,75  193,75  0   5
- Andreas Johansson    192,50  192,50  192,50  6
- Jan Ingvarsson   192,50  192,50  0   2
- Sören Fransson   188,75  187,50  190,00  10
- Anders Johansson 185,00  185,00  0   2
- Daniel Fransson  183,33  178,57  187,50  7
- Mats Wellermark  182,50  0   182,50  4
- Bengt Carlsson   181,25  181,25  0   4
- Andreas Larsson  175,00  163,57  185,00  6
- Barsom Calan         172,50  172,50  0   4
- Per-Olof Johansson   172,50  172,50  0   3
- Peter Ericson    171,25  171,25  0   2
- Jonas Wendel         170,00  170,00  0   4
- Stefan Lord          170,00  170,00  0   2
- Jonas Nilsson    166,25  166,25  0   4
- Mikael Nilsson   162,50  162,50  0   1
- Patrik Emanuelsson   162,50  162,50  0   2
- Lennart Johansson    162,00  162,00  0   3
- Jörgen Norman    160,00  160,00  0   2
- Maria Lord-Johansson 160,00  160,00  0   2
- Roger Larsson    160,00  160,00  0   2

Comment: Do you have any sample data and expected results?